# Perl multilingual sort: Want spaces to sort above letters

Tags: perl, unicode, multilingual

I have a the following Perl script, that sorts a list of words, encoded using utf-8:

```
use HTML::Entities;
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;
use utf8;

my @array = (
     "Another", 
     "An Other", 
     "Anóther", 
     "An Óther", 
     "Anòther", 
     "An Òther", 
     "Anôther", 
     "An Ôther", 
     "Anöther", 
     "An Öther", 
     "Anõther", 
     "An Õther"
     );

my $lang = "da";

printf ("Lang code is: %s\n", $lang);

my $coll = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(locale => "$lang");

my @result = $coll->sort(@array);


foreach my $item (@result){

print $item, "\n";
}
```

Here's what it outputs:

```
Lang code is: da
An Other
Another
An Óther
Anóther
An Òther
Anòther
An Ôther
Anôther
An Õther
Anõther
An Öther
Anöther
```

However, I would like it to output:

```
An Other
An Óther
An Òther
An Ôther
An Õther
An Öther
Another
Anóther
Anòther
Anôther
Anõther
Anöther
```

The rationale is that I would like the SPACE character to sort before other letters. Is there a way I can get my Collator object to help me do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the variable weighting to `'non-ignorable'`:

```
my $coll = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(
    locale   => $lang,
    variable => 'non-ignorable',
);
```

For details, see section [Variable Weighting](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Variable_Weighting) in the specification of the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA).